centered text across multicoulmn table with auto line break
I'm using xltabular and I have a table with multicolumns and multirows combined.
Everything is fine so far except for the multicolumn cells with one text in it. I want that to be centered, and it should also automatically line break within the tables max width of \textwidth. I'm really struggling with this. If I use the column-parameter c the auto line break will not work obviously and with X the text auto line breaks just in the first cell of the two combined.
below you can find a picture and my code

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{property a and b}} \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{property a}} & \textbf{\centering property b} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

\endhead
%
\multirow{4}{*}{headline a} 
& \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur} \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum} \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit} & \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua} 
& Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{headline b} 
& \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur} \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{X|}{Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum} \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit} & Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua} & Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat \\ \cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{1}{X|}{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur} & \\ \hline
\caption{caption}
\label{tab:table}\\
\end{xltabular}


Have a look the tabularray package. It makes it easy to merge cells and change the alignment.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried, but my project will not compile with that package. It throws errors Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model rgb:Hsb. and Undefined control sequence. but I'm not even using the package xcolor

Please show a small, but reproducible example.

Sorry what do you mean? My project is large and complicated. The package did not work and therefore I used another one. Debugging this error will take more time than using a different package I guess

\multicolumn{2}{X|} makes a p column as wide as an X column and you  want one twice as wide \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}X|}

the xcolor error is an xcolor issue that was forgotten ...

@DavidCarlisle omg thank you David! That is exactly what I needed.

Providing a minimal working example does not mean that you show your complete project code but, in this case, that you just add to the code you show the relevant document class and packages so that others can replicate the problem by copying the code. This way it is easier for others to help because it is clear which relevant packages you use.

\multicolumn{2}{X|} makes a p column as wide as an X column and you want one twice as wide:
\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}X|}


in addition: I added \centering in it to have centered text \multicolumn{2}{>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}X|}

@LudwigLoth yes although I wouldn't: large centred paragraphs are hard to read, your eye has no visual clue on where to pick up, and they just look horrible. (but perhaps your real text is shorter)

If you willing to use longtblr of tabularray package, the MWE is quite simple and short:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {caption},
  label = {tab:table}
                    ]{hlines, vlines,
                      colspec = {l X X},
                      row{1,2} = {font=\bfseries, c},
                      hspan=minimal, % to fill text in whole multi column cells
                      rowhead = 2
                     }
\SetCell[r=2]{} 
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{} property a and b        \\
                &   property a  &   property b              \\ 
%
\SetCell[r=4]{} headline a 
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
                                &                           \\
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum 
                                &                           \\
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 
                                &                           \\
                &   Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua 
                                &   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat 
                                                            \\
\SetCell[r=4]{} headline b 
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur 
                                &                           \\
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                                &                           \\
                &   \SetCell[c=2]{} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
                                & Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
                                                            \\
                &   Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
                                &   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat 
                                                            \\
                &   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur
                                &                           \\ 
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}


